# How to reference specific elements in Aurelia custom element's <slot>?

Tags: aurelia, custom-element, selectors-api

I want to create a custom fieldset in Aurelia and I need to set the style (width) of label elements within the "slot" tag (see example usage below). How can I access these elements? What I have so far is

```
<template>
  <require from="./ib-fieldset.css"></require>
  <fieldset style.bind="style">
    <legend>${title}</legend>
    <slot></slot>
  </fieldset>
</template>
```

and

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

export class IbFieldset {
  @bindable title: string;
  @bindable top: number;
  @bindable left: number;
  @bindable labelWidth: number;

  style: string;

  attached() {
    this.title = ` ${this.title} `;
    this.style = `position: absolute; top: ${this.top}px; left: ${this.left}px;`;
  }
}
```

I use it like that:

```
  <ib-fieldset title="Address" top="100" left="200" labelWidth="100">
    <label for="firstName">First name:</label>
    <input id="firstName" type="text">

    <label for="lastName">Last name:</label>
    <input id="lastName" type="text">
  </ib-fieldset><br>
```

I tried with jquery but I don't know how to select elements within the fieldset component only (not the whole page which can contain other fieldsets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like most situations in Aurelia, there is no need for jQuery.

GistRun: https://gist.run/?id=aa1e8239736e0de11f73116966af9ac9

**fieldset.html**

```
<template>
  <fieldset style="position: absolute; top: ${top}px; left: ${left}px;">
    <legend>${title}</legend>
    <slot ref="slotElement"></slot>
  </fieldset>
</template>
```

**fieldset.js**

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class IbFieldset {
  @bindable title: string;
  @bindable top: number;
  @bindable left: number;
  @bindable labelWidth: number;

  attached() {
    this.title = ` ${this.title} `;

    let labels = this.slotElement.querySelectorAll('label');

    for (let label of Array.from(labels)) {
        label.setAttribute('width', `${labelWidth}px`);
    }
  }
}
```

**consumer.html**

```
<require from="./fieldset"></require>

<ib-fieldset title="Address" top="100" left="200" label-width="100">
  <label for="firstName">First name:</label>
  <input id="firstName" type="text"/>

  <label for="lastName">Last name:</label>
  <input id="lastName" type="text"/>
</ib-fieldset><br>
```

To inject the element:

```
import {inject} from ‘aurelia-framework’;

@inject(Element)
export class IbFieldset {
    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    attached() {
        let labels = this.element.querySelectorAll('label');
        ……
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, but how can I set the labels' width (see my "labelWidth" property)?

Comment: Since the elements that are in the slot are defined in the consumer, it is easiest to simply set them there. See my updated answer. If you are creating a generic element and really want it to set the label widths, let me know and I'll show you how you can do that.

Comment: Hi Jeff, yes, the fieldset should handle that.

Comment: I updated my answer to show you one way you can have the custom element set the label widths internally. The gist is you get a reference to the slot element with `ref=slotElement` and use that in the view-model's `attached` method to set the label widths. Btw, your original code referred to  `labelWidth` in the html instead of `label-width`. A camel cased javascript bindable is referenced as a kabob cased attribute in the html element.

Comment: Yesss, it was `querySelectorAll('label');` what I was looking for. And I didn't get the `ref` working on the `<slot>` tag, I had to put a `<div>`around it and reference the div then. Thanks a lot, Jeff!

Comment: Hmm. Maybe ref doesn't work on slots. Anyway, if you don't want to use a div wrapper, you could simply inject the entire custom element and do querySelectorAll on that.

Comment: I added injecting the element at the bottom of my answer.